# Take screenshot for multiple browser in Allure with Protractor Configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, allure

I am very new in end to end testing environment. I am using Protractor framework, jasmine runner for my app testing. I run my test with Chrome and Internet explorer. But in allure report I can see the report only for one browser, not for both. Also screen shot is generated only for one browser. is there any configuration for allure, by which I can see the report for both browser.

My configuration file is

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
require('protractor/built/logger').Logger.logLevel = 3;
exports.config = {
    troubleshoot: true, // for protractor
    allScriptsTimeout: 1200000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/tests/**/0030*.e2e-spec.ts',
    ],

    multiCapabilities:[
    {
            'browserName' : 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': { 'args' : ['--disable-extensions']},
            'shardTestFiles': true,
            'maxInstances': 1,
            'unexpectedAlertBehaviour' : 'dismiss'
        },
        {
            'browserName': 'internet explorer',
            'se:ieOptions': {

                enablePersistentHover: true,
                'ie.ensureCleanSession': true,
            }
        }
        ],

      jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.141.0.exe'],


    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        isVerbose: true,
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1200000
    },
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    beforeLaunch: function() {
    }

    onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');

    capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
        console.log(caps);
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        var browserVersion = caps.get('version');
        const prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
        console.log(prePendStr);
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                    return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                },'image/png')();
                done();
            })
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        //savePath: './test/jasmine-nowshin/'
    }));
  }
};
```

**Updated code in test**

```
    let capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
let browserNameforSpec;
capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
    console.log(caps);
    let browserName = caps.get('browserName');
    let browserVersion = caps.get('version');
    browserNameforSpec = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
    console.log(browserNameforSpec);

});

describe( '0030 Test for login' + browserNameforSpec, function () { // this.browserNameforSpec value is undefined

    // 1.
    it('Navigate to the login page', async () => {
        await navigate.to.the(loginPage);
    });

    // 2
    it('Click onto language button', async() => {
        await click.onto(languageButton);
        await expect(languageDropdown.isDisplayed());
    });

    // 3
    it('English Language is selected', async() => {    
        await click.onto(englishLanguage);
        await expect(languageButton.getText()).toBe('English');
    });

    // 4.
    it('Correct user name is written into email field', async() => {
        await usernameField.click();
        await enter(correctUsername, into(usernameField));    
    });

    // 5.
    it('Correct password is written into password field', async() => {
            await passwordField.click().then(function () {
                passwordField.clear();
                enter(correctPassword, into(passwordField));
            })    
    });

    // 6.
    it('Login button is clicked and home page is opened', async() => {
        await click.onto(loginButton);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

currently allure does not support multi-browser reporting.

If the test name 'abc', it will create 2 reports with the same name and stack them but at the end of test you can see only 1. You can see this in the 'history' or 'retries' tab.

You can create custom listener for jasmine events, on start of test to add browser name or something else to create different names for each test so you can distinct them.

Information about creating custom reporter (listener)
https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_reporter

You can extract the browser name:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then((cap) => {
    browser.params.browserName = cap.get('browserName');
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide me some hints how can create a custom listener for jasmin events.

Comment: I have edited my code. I gave it to my updated question. But still not getting any browser info into tesr. Could you please check

Comment: browser.params.browserName is global variable, that contains the browser name, you have to create the custom reporter and/or manipulate the test name or allure reporter.

Comment: I have edited my code one more time. Sorry , but I am very new in handling this situation. Could you please have a look. I am having error annot read property 'browserName' of undefined

Comment: resolved promise from browser.getCapabilities() holds the properties. so should be  caps.get('param name for example browsername') or caps.browsename not a caps.caps_

Comment: I have modified code, by which I can get the browser name. But Now my question is if I want to set that name in front of spec, what should I do.

Comment: when you create a custom reporter, you can access the test name on start and modify it. Use the browser name or something else to distinct them. For the custom reporter, read at jasmine site and check examples.

Comment: @Inferno I tried with your way. But it does not help too much. because you are right I can change the spec description by using custom listener. But that report will not produce the allure report. If I want to change the spec description I have to do some thing like my edited code. Otherwise it alwas shows test for 1 suits. Please see my updated question